# What is the advantage of using a provider for the url?

Tags: angular

What is the advantage of using a custom url provider instead of the existing one in angular environments?

```
export const environment = {
    apiUrl: 'http://192.168.10.800/api'
}
```

And provder:

```
providers: [
  {
    provide: API_BASE_URL,
    useValue: environment.apiUrl
  }
]
```

Comment: I suppose you could override it in certain modules/services/components if you really wanted to. Or I could see use cases if you were making a library to be plugged into multiple apps... but i'd personally otherwise never consider using a provider and injection for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just injecting the api url as a token doesn't seem to provide much of a benefit.
However consider the case where you have more than one environment variable, e.g. `showDebugInformation`. This could well be something that you want to mock in a test so you can verify different scenarios.

Therefore I like to do something like this in my projects:

```
export abstract class EnvironmentService {
  abstract get showDebugInformation(): boolean;
}

@Injectable({provideIn: 'root'})
export class DefaultEnvironmentService implements EnvironmentService {
  get showDebugInformation() {
     return environment.showDebugInformation;
  };
}

// In your other services:

if (this.environmentService.showDebugInformation) {
  ...
}
```